# FunctionalTestCase Mule 3.6.0

Tags: unit-testing, mule

I'm migrating my FunctionalTestCase from Mule 3.5.0 to Mule 3.6.0, when I try to post a json like:

```
Map properties = new HashMap(); 
properties.put("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
properties.put("http.method", "POST"); 
muleMessage.addProperties(properties, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND); 
AbstractMuleContextTestCase.muleContext.getClient().send(url, muleMessage);
```

I always get NullPayload in the flow that I'm testing, how it's the proper way to do a post in the new version of Mule 3.6.0

Comment: Try with send(String url, MuleMessage message, OperationOptions operationOptions), using options set up tu use POST as method.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to set up to use POST method? I'm having trouble doing this.

Comment: Sure: ```newOptions().method("POST").build()```. That will give you the operationsOptions you need. Let me know if it works.

Comment: what is the package of the class Options?

Comment: HttpRequestOptionsBuilder. You can check out an example usage 
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/421f28d24f26e63df23c7e84294473a37a88676f/tests/integration/src/test/java/org/mule/test/integration/exceptions/RollbackExceptionStrategyTestCase.java (testHttpRedeliveryExhaustedRollbackUsingMuleClient)

Comment: Great! I created a proper answer in case anybody stumbles upon this again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MuleClient has a new method now to specify the request options, including the method to be used. This is: `send(String url, MuleMessage message, OperationOptions operationOptions)`. The operationOptions can be created in many ways, one of which is: `newOptions().method("POST").build()` to make a POST request.

An example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/421f28d24f26e63df23c7e84294473a37a88676f/tests/integration/src/test/java/org/mule/test/integration/exceptions/RollbackExceptionStrategyTestCase.java) in `testHttpRedeliveryExhaustedRollbackUsingMuleClient`.